# Use angular 9 on m1 Mac

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, apple-m1

I have a project that uses node 12 and angular 9 and I can't make it work on my new M1 Mac.

I installed node with nvm and used the latest version of npm for that version. I ran `npm i -g @angular/cli@9` to install angular. Using `which ng` it shows that it is actually installed, but if I do `ng --version` I get: An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory. I've tried many things: different versions and ways of installing node but nothing.

Also, if I try to do `npm I` in my project it gives me tons of errors. I tried matching the same versions of node, npm and angular from my previous intel Mac (where it worked) but nothing.

I hope someone can help me. I'm having such a hard time migrating to m1.

Comment: Try to use `npm v12` and not the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work by doing this.

Delete file package-lock.json and the node_modules folder, and then run npm install again.

If that doesn't work, try running these in order:

```
npm install
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it using node 14 an npm 9. Also I had to install python2 since node-gyp couldn't find it.